# How do I access Azure Storage "(Classic)" from an Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions

When accessing Azure storage from inside the function "Integrations" tab, it appears that it is only possible to link to a "new" storage account not a storage account that it listed as "(Classic)".

I have verified that the "(Classic)" storage account I want to connect with IS in the same region as the Azure App Service and Function that I am working with so it *should* appear but it does not.

How do I connect a function to a "(Classic)" Azure Storage account?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The UI storage picker does not show Classic accounts. However, you could achieve the same manually:

- create a new App Setting in your Web App pointing to the connection string to your Classic account
- In the Integrate tab, go to raw view and set `"connection": "YOURCONNECTIONNAME"` in the binding.

Comment: Is there any performance issue with this combination? Curious about that.

Comment: I wouldn't think so. I'd expect the Classic and new style storage accounts to have similar perf.

Comment: So is this by design or just an omission?

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis I would guess it was by design, given that classic storage accounts are over time all being replaced with new ones.